# Compiler Compliance 1.7

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am not able to switch strings `switch (face){` Im getting the error:

```
Cannot switch on a value of type String. Only convertible 
                      int values or enum constants are permitted
```

When I try to update my compiler compliance level it only goes to **1.6**

**Compiler Compliance Level:**
[image]

I also have tried multiple *JRE's and JDK's*:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look like your IDE does not have support for java 7. Which IDE are you using?

If you are using eclipse. For java 7 support you need to upgrade your eclipse to at least [Eclipse Indigo SR1e](http://www.eclipse.org/org/press-release/20110929_indigosr1.php) or newer version.

If you are using any other IDE check it supports java 7 or not.

And you should always use standard VM instead of MacOS x VM.

Comment: Im using eclipse, but that only takes me to about it, and the downloads at [eclipse downloads](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)  aren't for 32 bit mac. Is there a more direct link or something?

Comment: Thanks, but how can I convert my project into the new eclipse? I took it out of the workspace, deleted that empty file, and made a new workspace, since it couldn't convert the project. If I drag my project into the new workspace and restart eclipse, nothing happens :(

Comment: @Flipkidd  right click - > import ->  existing project in workspace